# AttributeError: module 'matplotlib.cbook' has no attribute '_check_in_list'

Tags: python-3.x, matplotlib

Given data from [this link](https://www.kaggle.com/rakannimer/air-passengers):

I try to plot it with `matplotlib`:

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

df['Month'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Month'], infer_datetime_format = True)
df = df.set_index('Month',inplace=False)    
# plot graph
plt.xlabel('date')
plt.ylabel('trafic flow count')
plt.plot(df)
```

But it raises the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<ipython-input-94-36d5bf32b0eb>", line 43, in <module>
    plt.xlabel('date')

  File "/Users/x/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/matplotlib/pyplot.py", line 1512, in xlabel

  File "/Users/x/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/matplotlib/pyplot.py", line 984, in gca
    _pylab_helpers.Gcf.set_active(ax.figure.canvas.manager)

  File "/Users/x/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/matplotlib/figure.py", line 1817, in gca
    self.clf(keep_observers=keep_observers)

  File "/Users/x/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/matplotlib/figure.py", line 1239, in add_subplot
    projection_class, kwargs, key = \

  File "/Users/x/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/matplotlib/axes/_subplots.py", line 77, in __init__
    """Change subplot geometry, e.g., from (1, 1, 1) to (2, 2, 3)."""

  File "/Users/x/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/matplotlib/axes/_base.py", line 523, in __init__
    self.set_yscale(yscale)

  File "/Users/x/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/matplotlib/axes/_base.py", line 1080, in cla
    if mpl.rcParams['ytick.minor.visible']:

  File "/Users/x/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/matplotlib/axes/_base.py", line 2710, in grid
    for _axis in self._get_axis_list():

  File "/Users/x/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/matplotlib/axis.py", line 1453, in grid

  File "/Users/x/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/matplotlib/axis.py", line 866, in set_tick_params
    if 'direction' in kw:

  File "/Users/x/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/matplotlib/axis.py", line 681, in __get__
    self.axes = axes

  File "/Users/x/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/matplotlib/axis.py", line 1792, in _get_tick
    **kwargs : `~.text.Text` properties.

  File "/Users/x/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/matplotlib/axis.py", line 176, in __init__
    ("_get_text1", "label1"),

  File "/Users/x/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/matplotlib/axis.py", line 474, in _get_tick1line
    self._loc = loc

  File "/Users/x/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/matplotlib/lines.py", line 397, in __init__
    self._invalidy = True

  File "/Users/x/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/matplotlib/markers.py", line 227, in __init__
    self.set_fillstyle(fillstyle)

  File "/Users/x/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/matplotlib/markers.py", line 264, in set_fillstyle
    cbook._check_in_list(self.fillstyles, fillstyle=fillstyle)

AttributeError: module 'matplotlib.cbook' has no attribute '_check_in_list'
```

Anyone could help? Many thanks at advance.

Comment: This issue is not reproducible. What version of matplotlib and pandas? At the conda prompt do `conda update --all` and select `y` to update.

Comment: Pandas: 1.1.4; matplotlib: 2.2.2, I've used `pip3` to install them.

Comment: No don't do that. I can see that you are using an anaconda distribution. You will fubar your environment by using pip to install / update packages that are already part of anaconda. The correct way is with `conda update --all`.

Comment: It seems conda to update packages is very slow. So I'm used to use pip.

Comment: That's because conda checks all the dependencies for the environment. As I said, do not use pip to update / reinstall packages already in the anaconda distribution. It is highly likely that you will need uninstall / reinstall Anaconda.

Comment: So for install packages, I should use `conda install xxx`?

Comment: If a package is not already installed and is not available through the conda distribution, it's okay to use `pip`. If the package is already installed or is available through conda, then use `conda`. `conda install <package>` or `conda update <package>`.